# THREE.ExplodeModifier hacking

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using the ExplodeModifier to duplicate the vertices so I can have individual control over `Face3` objects.
For my specific example, this alone looks visually poor, so I decided to add 3 extra faces (per existing face) so I can have a pyramid shape pointing inwards the geometry.

I managed to modify the ExplodeModifier and create the extra faces, however I get several errors:

> THREE.DirectGeometry.fromGeometry(): Undefined vertexUv and THREE.BufferAttribute.copyVector3sArray(): vector is undefined

I understand that now I have 9 extra vertices per face, so I need according uv's, and since I don't need a texture but a solid color I don't mind having the wrong uvs... So, I also duplicated the uvs and avoid the first warning but I can't get rid of the `copyVector2sArray`...

pseudo code:

```
var geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry( 200, 1 );
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { shading: THREE.FlatShading } );

var explodeModifier = new THREE.ExplodeModifier();
explodeModifier.modify( geometry );

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.addChild( mesh );
```

The Explode Modifier has this pseudo code:

```
var vertices = [];
var faces = [];

for ( var i = 0, il = geometry.faces.length; i < il; i ++ ) {
    (...)

    var extraFace1 = new THREE.Face3().copy(face)
    extraFace1.c = geometry.vertices[0]

    var extraFace2 = new THREE.Face3().copy(face)
    extraFace2.b = geometry.vertices[0]

    var extraFace3 = new THREE.Face3().copy(face)
    extraFace3.a = geometry.vertices[0]

    faces.push( extraFace1 );
    faces.push( extraFace2 );
    faces.push( extraFace3 );
}

geometry.vertices = vertices;
geometry.faces = faces;
```

```

I added an example [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/andrevenancio/vmqhjtLx/). It works, but I want to avoid the console warnings...

Comment: I made the question more readable and added the `javascript` tag for more visibility.

Comment: thanks @erip hopefully someone can help me with this :)

Comment: `.a`, `.b`, `.c` are indices. you're assigning a vector to them.

Comment: man I'm feeling stupid right now! thanks @mrdoob managed to fix it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @mrdoob I was assigning a `THREE.Vector3` and not an `index` to the added `THREE.Face3`.

```
 var extraFace1 = new THREE.Face3().copy(face)
 extraFace1.a = geometry.faces.length * 3 - 1

 var extraFace2 = new THREE.Face3().copy(face)
 extraFace2.b = geometry.faces.length * 3 - 1

 var extraFace3 = new THREE.Face3().copy(face)
 extraFace3.c = geometry.faces.length * 3 - 1
```

[jsfiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/andrevenancio/vmqhjtLx/)