# 'Vector is undefined' warning when cloning vertices in a THREE.Geometry object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to dynamically add new faces to a mesh. I keep getting this console warning:

> THREE.BufferAttribute.copyVector3sArray(): vector is undefined

This is the simplest example that still causes it. It works - this example correctly produces a single triangle that's a clone of the geometry's first face - but I can't get rid of the warning.

```
var vertices = this.body.geometry.vertices;
var faces = this.body.geometry.faces;

var face = faces[0];
var a = face.a;
var b = face.b;
var c = face.c;

var va = vertices[a].clone();
var vb = vertices[b].clone();
var vc = vertices[c].clone();

vertices = [];
vertices.push(va);
vertices.push(vb);
vertices.push(vc);

this.body.geometry.vertices = vertices;
this.body.geometry.faces = faces;
```

It looks a lot like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34278210/three-explodemodifier-hacking), except that I'm not accidentally assigning a vector to a vertex's index, so I can't use that solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the undefined vector was a vertex normal. Running

```
this.body.geometry.computeFlatVertexNormals();
```

solved the problem. (Alternatively, the normals could be calculated by running `computeFaceNormals()` or `computeVertexNormals()`.)